# How can I find path to pgctl.exe in Python on Windows for different versions of PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, python-3.8

Sitrep:

I need to find path to `pg_ctl.exe` on many Windows systems using Python (3.8) with potentially different PostgreSQL server versions installed on each system.

Ideally I'd like to find it for PostgreSQL instances installed in custom directories as well, including local installations ("for current user only"), which puts it somewhere in user's `AppData`.

Yes, I know it's a bit of tall order, but that's what I need to do.

Comment: There is no better way than to search the whole disk for files called `pg_ctl.exe`. Better might be to have the user configure the PostgreSQL binary path.

Comment: From a user experience point of view, I would prefer the program to look in "typical" folders and if undetected ask the user to specify a path. My 2-penny worth...